# How to refer to ExSheets question using "Chapter.Question" format?

Tags: cross-referencing, exsheets

I've successfully configured ExSheet questions to write "Exercise 1.1", "Exercise 1.2", and so on before each exercise. But when use `\ref{}` command to refer to them, I get "Exercise 1", "Exercise 2", and so on, without the chapter hook.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{book}

\usepackage[headings=runin]{exsheets} %[2015/02/09]

\usepackage{mdframed}

\SetupExSheets{counter-within={chapter}} \SetupExSheets{counter-format=ch.qu[1]} \SetupExSheets{label-format=ch.qu[1]} \SetupExSheets{question/pre-hook=\mdframed,question/post-hook=\endmdframed}

\begin{document}

\chapter{This is the title of the chapter}

\begin{question}[subtitle = This is the title of the question] \label{qu:question-label}

 Bla bla bla...   \end{question}

  Exercise~\ref{qu:question-label} has bla bla bla as the part of a question we call enunciado in Brazilian Portuguese (I don't know how to call it in English).

\end{document}
```

[image: Note how "Exercise~\ref{qu:question-label}" generates "Exercise 1" instead of "Exercise 1.1".]

Comment: The `label-format` is something different… add `\renewcommand\thequestion{\thechapter.\arabic{question}}` to your preamble (`exsheets`' counter settings are a bit strange due to something I once thought would be nice but in practice is rather counter-intuitive. I'm thinking of changing this in a v1.0…)

Comment: Apparently, your answer is currently not showed as an answer to my question, only as a comment. I have the option to answer my own question with your answer, but maybe I just let you do so to get the privileges.

Comment: If you want to I'll add an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\SetupExSheets{label-format=ch.qu[1]}` only has an effect if `exsheets`' `auto-label` option is used. But then it would add to *each* question

```
\label{ch.qu[1]}
```

so you'd only get multiple labels. What you actually need to do is

```
\renewcommand\thequestion{\thechapter.\arabic{question}}
```

---

I know that it is not intuitive having to do this in addition to `\SetupExSheets{counter-format=ch.qu[1]}` and I probably will do something about this for a yet to come v1.0 of `exsheets`.